# Finding number of ways to select k numbers that add upto n

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I need to find the number of ways to select `k` numbers that add upto `n`, where `1<= k <= n`. The numbers are not to be repeated. I am trying a recursive solution, which I think runs into an infinite loop.

```
void noofways(int firstnumchosen,int sum,int numofnum)
{
   if(sum<0)
      return;

   if(sum==0 && numofnum!=0)
      return;

   if(sum==0 && numofnum==0){
      globalcount++;
      return;
   }

   if(numofnum<=0)
      return;

   // not choosing the first number
   noofways(firstnumchosen+1,sum,numofnum);

   //choosing the first number
   noofways(firstnumchosen+1,sum-firstnumchosen,numofnum-1);
}
```

`globalcount` is a global variable here. To get the sum of 7 by using 3 numbers, I will be calling the function `noofways(1,8,3);`. To  make myself more clear, the solution set consists of (1,2,5), (1,3,4) and so on.

Why fdoes my function run infinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`noofways(x, y, z)` calls `noofways(x+1, y, z)`, so x grows unbounded.

You need to test if x is too large and return during parameter check:

```
if (firstnumchosen > something)
    return;
```

This isn't the only problem, but it is the cause of the infinite loop.